# How to prevent widgets from placing themselves under notifications bar / camera?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-layout

In all my apps, I get the problem of having my widgets place themselves under the camera/notification bar.

I usually just place a sizedbox at the top to prevent it but it feels like a bad solution.

Is there any other way to prevent it?

[image: Simple text widget gets placed under camera]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue you have to wrap your widget inside a [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

```
SafeArea(
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you have to put your widget inside [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

If you want to use SafeArea in only top and bottom directions, then you can specify in following way.

```
SafeArea( 
    left: false, 
    top: true, 
    bottom: true, 
    right: false, 
    child: Text('Your Widget'), 
  )
```